# How do I create an index on a computed column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a large SELECT query where in the WHERE clause, I have something like:

```
WHERE isnull(RCTL.day_id, '') = isnull(@Pday_id, isnull(RCTL.day_id, ''))
```

The ISNULL() on RCTL.day_id is causing a huge performance bottleneck. I have been reading online that I need to create a computed column on the table for ISNULL(day_id, 0) and then index this column.

Is this the correct approach and if so, is this correct?

```
 alter table dbo.tc_route_control add blank_day_id as (isnull(day_id, 0))

create nonclustered index ix_test1 on dbo.tc_route_control (blank_day_id)
```

Comment: There's a good answer to this question over on dba.stackexchange: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168351/sql-server-is-it-possible-to-create-a-calculated-index

Comment: You need to create the computed column as PERSISTED

Comment: thanks to both of you. i tried to do this but it didnt work and i think it was because i left out the persisted.